# can not allocate - system crash

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to apply a heap on a vector.

vector looks like this:

```
struct VECTOR{
    int *m_items;
    int m_size;
    int m_count;
    int m_initSize;
    int m_extendSize;
};
```

The heap looks like this:

```
struct Heap
{
    VECTOR* m_vector;
    int     m_elements;
};
```

In my test file, I allocated the vector, filled it with items, and printed it all just to be sure it works.
Then, I tried allocating a heap, in order to point it to the vector, and "heapify" the vector:

```
Heap* Heap_Build(VECTOR* _vector)
{
    Heap* heap = NULL;

    assert(_vector);    
    heap = (Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap));
    assert(heap);
    heap->m_vector = _vector;
    heap->m_elements = VectorGetCount(_vector);

    HeapifyAll(heap);

    return heap;
}
```

The system crashes trying allocating the heap.
I searched for problems close to mine, but couldn't find an answer
specific to my problem (although I tried them all).
It shouldn't be the heap's size - fixed as 8 bytes.
I even tried `-pthread` for just in case.

I get:

```
malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

in gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

and in valgrind memcheck:

```
==4282== Invalid write of size 4
==4282==    at 0x8048A62: VectorAdd (in /home/itai/Desktop/0325-heap/a.out)
==4282==    by 0x8048D0D: Heap_Test (in /home/itai/Desktop/0325-heap/a.out)
==4282==    by 0x8048902: main (in /home/itai/Desktop/0325-heap/a.out)
==4282==  Address 0x41f1070 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
==4282==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
 ...
--4282-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--4282-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x20746168;  sp: 0x627eca88
```

Does anyone have any idea why it won't work?
It should be simple allocation, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Does the allocation of heap work if you remove the rest of your code? My guess is that some other part of your code is corrupting memory which is causing malloc to fail

Comment: Please show a COMPLETE small, working, compilable program with a main() ,etc. not snippets.

Comment: Your stack trace does not correspond to your code.  Your code is failing in VectorAdd in Heap_Test.  You're just showing us Heap_Build.

Comment: you are getting "Aborted (core dumped)" that means a file named "core" in current directory must be there is exist then analysis of core file using gdb will help more.if core file is not created then fire "ulimit -c unlimited" and then run your program file will created.

Comment: thisisdog and cup were right.
i just found a bug in the vector, that ruined my used-to-be beautiful heap-memory.
thank you all guys!
sorry for troubling.

Comment: `valgrind` is telling you that you're allocating 0 bytes: `==4282==  Address 0x41f1070 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd` — why are you writing to a block of length 0? You missed out the interesting parts of the diagnostic — the stack trace showing where `malloc()` was called.  However, you should concentrate on that code before you do anything else — like heaping the previously allocated vector.